# Should I create BaseActivity/Presenter and View in Mosby MvP concept?

Tags: android, mosby

I'm trying to understand concept of MvP design pattern. I mean, I get it, its quite easy. The main problem is optimal implementation. I tried to make my own BaseActivity, BasePresenter and BaseView just to extract part of a joint from all of my activities, I've done this this way:

BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<T extends BasePresenter<? extends IBaseView>> extends FragmentActivity implements IBaseView {

    protected T presenter;
    private ActivityConfig activityConfig;

    @Override
    final protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activityConfig = getConfig();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        presenter = createPresenter();

        setContentView();
        initLibraries();

        prepareView(savedInstanceState);
        addFragments();
    }

    protected abstract ActivityConfig getConfig();

    protected abstract T createPresenter();

    protected abstract void prepareView(Bundle savedInstanceState);

    protected abstract void addFragments();

    private void setContentView(){
        View root = View.inflate(this, activityConfig.layoutId, null);
        setContentView(root);
    }

    private void initLibraries() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

    }

    @Override
    public BaseActivity getCurrentContext() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public T getPresenter() {
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

BasePresenter

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<T extends IBaseView> {

    public abstract void loadData(boolean refresh);

}
```

BaseView

```
public interface IBaseView {

    BaseActivity getCurrentContext();

    BasePresenter getPresenter();
}
```

It works fine but I feel like this is bad designed so I want to use Mosby instead. The problem is that all of the tutorials don't touch aspect of base classes, they just use Mosby's ones as base (with is bad I suppose? couse I have to duplicate my code (Butterknife.bind() for example). So can you guys give me some good designed quickstart classes for Mosby MVP or give me some tips how should I divide my project? Thanks!

Comment: There are many different approaches to MVP on android, each one of them with *pros* and *cons*, it is hard to say which one is right or better and you will have to find one for yourself that suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I see two possibilities:

1. You could extend from Mosby's `MvpActivity` as your base class and add your staff like `initView()`, `initLibraries()` etc. So that `BaseActivity<P extends BasePresenter<? extends BaseView>> extends MvpActivity<P> implements BaseView`. Then `MyFooActivity extends BaseActivity<FooPresenter>`. So you include Butterknife once in `BaseActivity` and it should work. However, you might have to duplicate that code like Butterknife.bind()` for Fragments, as Activity and Fragments obviously don't have the same super class. I will show you how to solve that above.
2. Do the other way around: Integrate Mosby's functionality into your `BaseActivity`. Mosby is build with the principle of **"favor composition over inheritance"**. So what does this actually mean? Mosby offers a `ActivityMvpDelegate`. As the name already suggests this delegate does all the work of instantiating Presenter etc. But instead of inheriting from `MvpActivity` you use this delegate and invoke the corresponding delegate methods. Actually Mosby's `MvpActivity` is doing exactly that if you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/blob/master/mvp/src/main/java/com/hannesdorfmann/mosby/mvp/MvpActivity.java). So instead of extending from Mosby's`MvpActivity` you simply use `MvpActivityDelegate` in your `BaseActivity`.

So what about duplicating code like `Butterknife.bind()` i.e. in Activity and Fragment. Well, Mosby can share his code like instantiating Presenter etc. between Activity and Fragment because both use the mosby delegate.

So you could apply the same principle: You could put the shared code into a delegate and call the delegate from both, activity and fragments. 
The question is: is it worth i.e. `Butterknife.bind()` is just one single call. You would also have to make one single call `yourDelegate.doSomething()` ...
But if you have to reuse "critical code" between activity and fragments then favor composition like Mosby does.

If you know that you are only working with `Activites` then extending from Mosby's MvpActivity would also be a good option as described in 1. solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to sockeqwe's first answer.

It is perfectly fine to create your own base class where it makes sense. It's also pretty straightforward.

For example, I needed to create a base `Fragment` with some default behavior. All you need to do is duplicate the base generic type signature and pass it along to the base class.

For example:

`public abstract class MyBaseFragment<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> extends MvpFragment<V, P>`